# Is there any method like Iphone's application didfinishlaunchingwithoptions in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am implementing push notification WP7 it coming successfully in my application.I am executing specific code after receiving the notification.But the problem is that when the application is in background or closed and the push notification arrives at that time only the application's first page is coming.I want to execute the code when the application starts by notification.
In Iphone there is a method applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions, in this method we can check whether the application is started by push notification or not.
Is there any method like that in WP7?

Answer (score 0):

For a push notification, you set a uri for navigation. Add a url parameter to this, and handle it in the [`OnNavigatedTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) method.

Comment: As i am new to WP7 i am not able to understand your answer.Can you explain it in more detail or with a sample code?

Comment: There's sample code in the link. And here's a quick search on how to parse Uri's: http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2011/03/passing-values-to-windows-phone-7-pages-uri-paremeters-or-querystring/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I know this concept but how to use it along with push notification. My basic question is whenever I send push notification to the application and if application is running then it comes to PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived event successfully. But its not working whenever application is not running or minimized. At that time its only opening the application  if we touch the Toast push.

Comment: Yes? That's the intended behaviour.